# Why is "/v2/api-docs" getting appended in Swagger base url

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have a springboot application with springfox swagger 2.9.2, for one of my microservice the swagger base url generated in the swagger docs is appending "/v2/api-docs" at the end, for seemingly no apparent reason.

[image]

Here is what my application properties file looks like

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
server.contextPath=/xxxxxxxxxxxx-enterprise/v2/sas
server.port=8070
```

I have a feeling I am missing something silly.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is the swagger service descriptions default path

From Springfox documentation: https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#customizing-the-swagger-endpoints

This can be customized by overriding "springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path" property

Comment: I know about the documentation part, I was asking why the *base url* is having "/v2/api-docs" at the end.

Comment: Well if you know about it then read it, because it clearly says that "/v2/api-docs" will be the default path to your endpoints documentation, and if you want to change it or get rid of it, you should override that property

Comment: My question asks for removing "v2/api-docs" from the end of the API url NOT the endpoint documentation URL which I want to remain as is, so not a duplicate question.

Comment: Okay, can you share your swagger @Configuration class where you defined your Docket bean ?